# How To Replace New Dll In Bin Folder In IIS 6.1?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, iis, iis-6

I Have a WCF Service Host that is deployed on an IIS 6.1.

I want to update one .dll in the WCF Service Host Bin Folder.

When I replaced the .dll in the Bin folder and restarted IIS 6.1 my new .dll didn't update and my application runs with the old .dll.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure it is grabbing that DLL from that location?

Comment: Yes i am sure because i find bin folder path from iis. for example i click on the host in iis and select advance setting and go to physical path and copy dll in bin folder. @bwtrent